# Page not mobile friendly error when testing on google mobile friendly test

Tags: responsive-design

I test my site url on google mobile friendly test. It showing me page is mobile friendly but some times it is showing me that page is not mobile friendly. So why it is happen. Please help me out for this. I added some codes in htaccess but not getting positive thing. Site in wordpress.

URL : https://www.example.com/test/

Answer (score 0):

This could happen when the google mobile bot is not able to fetch and render the page correctly for the mobile platforms.

If you test this in your search console, you can see the errors for the static assets not getting loaded for mobile. It could happen due to a variety of reasons based on your Wordpress website configurations and plugins.

If you are not using google search console, make sure you use it to figure out the actual cause of these issues.

Check out this detailed blog for the fix relates to static content delivery - [Fix Page not friendly issue](https://digitoguide.com/not-mobile-friendly-wordpress/)